# Exception when deserializing Oauth2 session from Redis on Spring Sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-cloud, spring-session

I´m testing a micro-service architecture with Spring Boot, but there's an exception when Spring Session tries to deserialize the session from redis.

The architecture is the following:

Redis <--(Session) Api Gateway (Oauth2 Atuhentication)--> Uaa Server

Redis <--(Session) Admin

[Gateway](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/double)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class GatewayApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> user(Principal user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", user.getName());
        map.put("roles", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(((Authentication) user)
                .getAuthorities()));
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.httpBasic().and().logout().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

Gateway aplication.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: treasure
      clientSecret: treasure_secret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
  sessions: ALWAYS
zuul:
  routes:
    admin:
      url: http://localhost:8082
      sensitive-headers:
spring:
  redis:
    host: 192.168.99.100
```

[Admin](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/double)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@RestController
public class AdminApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> user(Principal user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", user.getName());
        map.put("roles", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(((Authentication) user)
                .getAuthorities()));
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/unauthenticated.html", "/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following stacktrace. I did noticed that the Gateway Application can deserialize correctly, but it uses the DefaultListableBeanFactory on the point of exception. The Admin application uses this StaticListableBeanFactory though.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.StaticListableBeanFactory to field org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject.beanFactory of type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory in instance of org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:81) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:335) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:279) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:102) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:432) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:402) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:326) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:343) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.StaticListableBeanFactory to field org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject.beanFactory of type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory in instance of org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:79) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.StaticListableBeanFactory to field org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject.beanFactory of type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory in instance of org.springframework.aop.scope.DefaultScopedObject
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2024) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:557) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas on how to configure or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is related to the following fix

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15766

Upgrade to spring 4.3.10 should improve the situation.